# DropDownListFor on Edit page passing null value to controller on POSTBACK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, postback, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an ASP MVC3 project that's using a partial view in the edit page. It loads the proper values into the `DropDownListFor`, however on the POST BACK the items are suddenly null.

The view uses a view model in order to incorporate a couple SQL tables. As part of that view model, a `List` collection object of type `BankListAgentId` is used to store all agent Id's related to a specific client. In order to properly POST and edit the items in the collection object, I followed [Steve Sanderson's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) regarding variable length objects in ASP MVC.

This process works perfectly for the agent Id's, however the state codes are all null once the user hits "Save."

Here is the code from the view

```
@model Monet.ViewModel.BankListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Stat(s) Fixed</legend>
        <table id="fixedRows">
            <tr>
                <th>State Code</th>
                <th>Agent ID</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Fixed)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId))
                {
                    @Html.Partial("FixedPartialView", item) 
                }
            }
        </table>
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Add another", "BlankFixedRow", null, null, new { id = "addFixed" })
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is the partial

```
@model Monet.Models.BankListAgentId


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Variable"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode,
                (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.StateCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentId)
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();" style="float:right;">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

And here is the view model

```
public class BankListViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string LastChangeOperator { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastChangeDate { get; set; }

    public List<BankListAgentId> Fixed { get; set; }
    public List<BankListAgentId> Variable { get; set; }
    public List<BankListAttachments> Attachments { get; set; }

    public BankListViewModel()
    {
        //Initialize Fixed and Variable stat Lists
        Fixed = new List<BankListAgentId>();
        Variable = new List<BankListAgentId>();

        Models.BankListAgentId agentId = new BankListAgentId();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Fixed.Add(agentId);
            Variable.Add(agentId);

        }

        //Initialize attachment Lists
        Attachments = new List<BankListAttachments>();
        Attachments.Add(new BankListAttachments());
    }
}
```

Here is the original POST to the edit page from the controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        BankListMaster banklistmaster = db.BankListMaster.Find(id);
        BankListViewModel viewModel = new BankListViewModel();
        viewModel.BankName = banklistmaster.BankName;
        viewModel.LastChangeDate = banklistmaster.LastChangeDate;
        viewModel.LastChangeOperator = banklistmaster.LastChangeOperator;

        List<BankListAgentId> agentId = (from c in db.BankListAgentId
                                         where c.ID == id
                                         select c).ToList();

        foreach (var bankListAgentId in agentId)
        {
            string value = bankListAgentId.FixedOrVariable.Trim();
            if (value.Equals("Fixed"))
            {
                viewModel.Fixed.Add(bankListAgentId);
            }
            else
            {
                viewModel.Variable.Add(bankListAgentId);
            }
        }

        viewModel.Attachments = (from c in db.BankListAttachments
                                 where c.ID == id
                                 select c).ToList();

        SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NA", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "US", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" });
        ViewBag.StateCodeList = tmpList;

        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.BankListAgentId, "ID", "FixedOrVariable", banklistmaster.ID);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

public partial class BankListAgentId
{
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FixedOrVariable { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }

    public virtual BankListMaster BankListMaster { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please add your model to post

Comment: added view model to the post :)

Comment: also add post ActionResult

Comment: Just added the edit action

Comment: dont see StateCode in model

Comment: No, it's a table in our database. BankListMaster's primary key of `Id` is used as a foreign key on this table. I'll post this model as well.

Comment: Yes, that is the only model used. The main edit page uses a view model.

Comment: and the action method gets an int called id?

Comment: After a lot of reading, I think I finally understand how the Parent and Partial do their binding. It all seems to flow, assuming that statecode is populated properly. Only obvious issue i see is, you should not have the default value for the dropdownlistfor. I can't be sure that's causing your error, but I gotta wonder...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a Partial view like an EditorTemplate.  Partial Views and EditorTemplates are different.  You can think of a partial view as a server side include with some extra stuff.

So, the problem here is that you are passing a different model to the partial than used in the parent class.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Fixed)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId))
    {
        @Html.Partial("FixedPartialView", item) 
    }
}
```

When you submit your model, the helpers in your partial view render the code as if the model is Fixed, so it formats and names the items in your partials incorrectly.  In this case, the default model binder has no idea that "item" is in a collection called "Fixed" because you've removed the context of that by iterating over a foreach loop and rending only from the contained item.

I suggest that instead of using a partial view, you use an EditorTemplate, as this is what they are designed to handle (rendering types within an object), and they automatically handle collections.

Alternatively, if you wish to render the partial then don't pass in a sub-model and just let it render from the parent.  Otherwise, you will have to do a lot of work to make sure you have the right naming inside the partial.

Or, you if you only need to post this collection of items, then you can make sure your Post action accepts an `IEnumerable<Fixed>` instead of your parent model.

Comment: "Alternatively, if you wish to render the partial then don't pass in a sub-model and just let it render from the parent." - Could you point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try using editor templates rather than injecting partials in a loop.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Fixed)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgentId))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(item => item, "FixedPartialView") 
        }
    }
```

Then place your FixedPartialView.cshtml into an appropriate EditorTemplates folder. The binding, I believe, will be much more intuitive for the framework.

Comment: EditorTemplates automatically iterate over collections, there is no need to do it this way.  I'm doubtful it will render the correctly named form fields the way you are doing it as well.

Comment: Going off the cuff a little above, but I have had the principle of it working multiple times. May have to be an iterative for loop with index, but it certainly does work. 

List binding is a bit of a sticky wicket in MVC, I have to admit.